# Changing tf_prefix for turtlebot

Tags: launch-file, frames, namespace, frame-id, tf-prefix

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that similar questions were already asked here but I still haven't found an answer to my question.
I would like to create a system of several turtlebots with different names (e.g. "pinky", "inky" etc). I need to navigate them and, therefore, I need different tf_prefix for each turtlebot. However, I don't know how to change the tf_prefix for odom frame. I changed the namespace by organizing each turtlebot in a separate group (e.g. group ns="pinky"). But when I set  in a launch file, the odom frame remains unchanged. I had similar problems with turtlebot_gazebo; however, I solved it by writing group name and tf_prefix together. Nevertheless, this solution doesn't work for the real turtlebot.
Here is my launch file:

```
<launch>
   <!--Here I try to set the namespace and add tf_prefix-->
   <group ns="pinky">
   <param name="tf_prefix" value="pinky" />
   
  <arg name="base"       default="$(optenv TURTLEBOT_BASE kobuki)"/>  <!-- create, rhoomba -->
  <arg name="battery"    default="$(optenv TURTLEBOT_BATTERY /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0)"/>  <!-- /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0 in 2.6 or earlier kernels-->
  <arg name="stacks"     default="$(optenv TURTLEBOT_STACKS hexagons)"/>  <!-- circles, hexagons -->
  <arg name="3d_sensor"  default="$(optenv TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR kinect)"/>  <!-- kinect, asus_xtion_pro -->
  <arg name="simulation" default="$(optenv TURTLEBOT_SIMULATION false)"/>

  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="$(arg simulation)"/>

  <include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/includes/robot.launch.xml">
  <arg name="base" value="$(arg base)" />
  <arg name="stacks" value="$(arg stacks)" />
  <arg name="3d_sensor" value="$(arg 3d_sensor)" />
  </include>
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/includes/mobile_base.launch.xml">
  <arg name="base" value="$(arg base)" />
  </include>
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/includes/netbook.launch.xml">
  <arg name="battery" value="$(arg battery)" />
  </include>

</group>
</launch>
```

I am not able to attach photo, but here is the description of my tree:

---

```
                                odom                             pinky/base_footprint
                                   |                                       |
                                  \/                                      \/
                           base_footprint                          pinky/base_link
                                                                          |
                                                        /                 |       \
                                                   pinky/...        pinky/...   pinky/...
```

Could someone please help me solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239487/changing-tf_prefix-for-turtlebot/) by [David_Zizu](https://answers.ros.org/users/27401/david_zizu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2016-07-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally I found a solution to my problem.
I had to add the name of the robot to the **base.yaml**.
There are two lines which specify "Name of odometry TF frame" and "Name of base TF frame." As a result I just had to add name of the robot to odom and base_footprint frames.

---

Originally posted by [David_Zizu](https://answers.ros.org/users/27401/david_zizu/) with karma: 46 on 2016-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [j_salfity](https://answers.ros.org/users/27623/j_salfity/) on 2017-06-23**:
How did you add the name of the robot to odom and base_footprint?
robot_name_odom or robot_name/odom ??
I'm struggling with the same problem and can't get either solution to work.
Thanks

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2018-10-07**:
Yes: please post code as well as or instead of a "this is what I did" description.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to find where the `robot_pose_ekf` is started for your robot (that depends on the base if I am not mistaken). Should look something like this:

```
<node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
<remap from="imu_data" to="imu/data"/>
<param name="freq" value="10.0"/>
<param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>
<param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
<param name="odom_used" value="true"/>
<param name="imu_used" value="true"/>
<param name="vo_used" value="false"/>
<param name="output_frame" value="odom"/>
</node>
```

And change it to

```
<node  pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf" >
<param name="freq" value="30.0"/>
<param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>
<param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
<param name="odom_used" value="true"/>
<param name="imu_used" value="true"/>
<param name="vo_used" value="false"/>
<param name="output_frame" value="odom"/>
<remap from="odom" to="$(arg robot_name)/odom"/>
</node>
```

Pay attention to the last line before `</node>`. Where you set `robot_name` to pinky.

Hope that helps. Did the trick for me if I remember correctly but it has been a while.

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2016-07-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David_Zizu](https://answers.ros.org/users/27401/david_zizu/) on 2016-07-15**:
Thank you for the response! Unfortunately your solution didn't work, I don't have the node robot_pose_ekf for the simple launch file.